Convert JSON string column value as join value
I need help on how to convert this table value
Table 1:
ID | DATA_1 | SHIFT_ID
----------------------------
1  | 100    | ["1","2","3"]
2  | 150    | ["1","3"]
3  | 50     | ["3"]

Table 2:
ID | SHIFT_NAME
----------------
1  | Morning
2  | Afternoon
3  | Night

into something like this
ID | DATA_1 | SHIFT_ID
----------------------------
1  | 100    | Morning, Afternoon, Night
2  | 150    | Morning, Night
3  | 50     | Night

Here's my try but I'm still confused how to properly combine, and not sure if this the correct approach
WITH T2 AS
(
    SELECT ID, SHIFT_NAME FROM T2
)
SELECT T1.*, T2.*
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON T2.ID IN (T1.ID)

Thank you!

Be great to see what you tried and where you got stuck.

This isn't a conversion, it's a very clear sign that JSON was the wrong choice. If you need to JOIN that data, it should be stored as proper columns in a many-to-many table. Anything else just covers up the design problem. JSON text can't be indexed, so anything you try will be slow and get slower with more data

The quick fix is to use eg OPENJSON to convert the JSON array into rows and JOIN with them, then group and use STRING_AGG to combine the names. It's ugly, slow, but the only real solution until the schema is fixed

What will you do if one of the SHIFT_IDs doesn't match an actual shift entry? There's no way to guarantee the JSON values are correct without foreign keys, and those can't be applied to partial values. Should it be an empty string, a null, some kind of warning, or should the missing value be ignored?

This isn't a conversion. This requires treating the values as actual table values and JOINing them with the shift names. It's a very clear sign that JSON was the wrong choice. If you need to JOIN that data, it should be stored as proper columns in a many-to-many table. Anything else just covers up the design problem.
JSON text can't be indexed, so anything you try will be slow and get slower with more data. Worse, there's no way to guarantee that the array values are correct because it's impossible to specify foreign key constraints between substrings and table keys.
In the meantime, you can use OPENJSON which was first introduced in SQL Server 2016 to return the JSON data as a table, JOIN with the shift names and group the values once again to get the names as a comma-separated value.
Given these tables:
create table shifts(id int primary key,shift_name nvarchar(20));

create table shift_data (id int primary key, data_1 nvarchar(20), shift_id nvarchar(200));

insert into shifts(id,shift_name)
values
(1,'Morning'),
(2,'Afternoon'),
(3,'Night');


insert into shift_data(id,data_1,shift_id)
values 
(1,100,'["1","2","3"]'),
(2,150,'["1","3"]'),
(3,50 ,'["3"]')

This query will read the JSON data and proceed to JOIN with the names :
select 
    shift_data.id,
    shift_data.data_1, 
    string_agg(shift_name,',') as shift_id
from shift_data 
    outer apply OPENJSON(shift_id) with (sid int '$') as ids
    inner join shifts on shifts.id=sid
group by shift_data.id,shift_data.data_1

This produces :
id  data_1  shift_id
1   100     Morning,Afternoon,Night
2   150     Morning,Night
3   50      Night

The function OPENJSON(shift_id) with (sid int '$') essentially produces the missing many-to-many table. It can't generate indexes though so as the shift_data table grows larger, the query will get slower.

First note that your DB structure could be much better. It's no good idea to save lists in columns. Better separate them!
But let's focus on a possible query that produces the desired result.
-- Build a CTE with id, data_1 and shift_id
-- Foreach shift_id from the comma-separated list, an own row will be created 
WITH t1
AS
  (SELECT 
    id, data_1, value AS shift_id
   FROM table1
   -- Split the comma-separated list into rows
   CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(shift_id))
SELECT 
  t1.id, t1.data_1, 
  -- Build a comma-separated list of the shift names
  -- Note1: Are you sure this column should be named shift_id and not shift_names?
  -- Note2: You might add an ORDER BY clause in STRING_AGG if intended
  STRING_AGG(t2.shift_name, ', ') AS shift_id
FROM 
  -- Join the CTE which is a "redesigned" table1 with table2
  t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.shift_id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.data_1
ORDER BY t1.id;

Try out on this sample fiddle

It doesn't. There's no reason to split. SQL Server introduced JSON functions in the same version as STRING_SPLIT. Splitting can easily produce unexpected results because it doesn't understand what's a value or separator, or whether a comma is inside a text value

@PanagiotisKanavos You're right OPENJSON should be prefered, I edited the query. Thank you.
